# Is there a core method in views that can pad numbers with leading zeros?

Tags: 7, views, entities

## Setup

I am building a view that outputs human usable id's. These ids would look best if padded to 3 characters. For example the episodes of a tv show may look best if they are formated:

01-01 (Season 1 episode 1)
10-05 (Season 10 Episode 5)
03-22 (Season 03 Episode 22)

## Problem

In my node I'm storing a simple integer (1-100). I want to keep the value as an integer not a string. How do I pad the integer with leading zeros on output.

Using simple php would be a simple `str_pad($value, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);` but I do not want to execute php in my views or even enable the php module/filter.

## Solution

The solution must:

- Use a core ability of views
- Not require me to execute php stored in the database (not enable php module or anything equivalent)
- Must allow me to maintain the field as an integer input/storage

I could probably write the views plugin for this but I was hoping their was already something available like a views integer format or something like that.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Please add an explicit question in the question body, one that is not on the lines of "Any ideas?" The title doesn't count as explicit question.

Comment: Read the title of the post. It is a concise clean question.  Also i have 200 reputation on this site and more on other in network sites been using stack exchange for 5 years.

Comment: As I said,  the question title doesn't count as asking a question. You aren't asking a question, but making a request.

Comment: I don't think you know what a question is. A question is a request for information.  A good question has a correct or best answer. My title is actually a yes or no question which is about as easy as it gets. A best answer would provide an option closest to my requirements and Drupal coding standards. You are free to not like my question but it meets all the requirements of the stack exchange network. If you still don't like it flag it and go away.

Comment: Since there isn't any explicit question, the question says _I was hoping their was already something available like a views integer format or something like that._ and you aren't accepting an answer suggesting how to achieve it with code, I take the question is a request for suggesting/finding a module implementing a plugin, and I will flag it for closing it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `/sites/all/themes/yourtheme/` folder and in **template.php** add the following code:

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_views_view_fields($vars){

  if ($vars['view']->name == "view_name" && $vars['view']->current_display == "block_1") {
    $vars['fields']['field_example']->content = str_pad($vars['fields']['field_example']->raw, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT);
  }

}
```

- replace **yourtheme** with the actual name of your theme
- replace **view_name** with the name of your view.
- replace **block_1** with the [machine name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbNIb.jpg) of your view.
- replace **example** with the name of your field (2 replacements).

Lastly, in Drupal, clear/flush your cache to see the changes.

Comment: This does not use a module or views setting. And while this may be a reasonable use of theme preprocessor Im not a fan of overriding views in the theme layer. Better to do it in a view_post_query hook or something like that in a custom module. Still looking for a module.

Comment: @danielson317 you will end up with the same result...

Comment: [what is the hook to preprocess a view?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60271/what-is-the-hook-to-preprocess-a-view)

Comment: Yes but with much cleaner code. Better to tie functionality to the code not the theme. For example if i have multiple user selectable themes this solution would require multiple implementations. In general php in the theme layer is a bad idea.

Comment: Hook views pre render is what i was trying to remember. Been a while since i used it. https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7.x-3.x still a abetter solution is to write a simple field formatter so its in the db instead of the code.

Comment: @danielson317 `abetter solution is to write a simple field formatter so its in the db instead of the code` might be worth trying **[Allow number to start with ZERO when stored in mysql integer field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2786193/allow-number-to-start-with-zero-when-stored-in-mysql-integer-field)**

Comment: I think my last statement wasn't clear. I meant it would be better to write a views field formatter. That way the views settings are in the database. Then when i update the view i don't have to remember the php code overrides i did to it. Thats why I'm looking for a module not a php code implementation.

Comment: Requests for module recommendations is something we don't do here @danielson317, it doesn't fit the Q+A format well. That's why you'll often find that people offer practical solutions here rather than linking off to a possibility elsewhere. As an aside, I think your requirements are at odds with what's physically possible here, insofar as your solution must _Use a core ability of views_. Core views doesn't have this ability, so currently you're simply out of luck. Yes writing a custom field handler is an option, but you'll have to do that as a "php code implementation" in a custom module, so..

Comment: ..that's ruled out too by the current requirements. It's hard to see how you're going to solve this unless you relax the rules here. A views pre-render hook would also need to be a "php code implementation" in a custom module, for example

Comment: "We dont do request for modules here" that's inconsistent with nearly half the questions i see here. How can i do x the drupal way is essentially a module request. My requirements are perfectly reasonable. No php filter is a common security requirement. Not screwing with the theme layer with custom php is drupal best practices. Id accept a good php implementation bit i havnt seen one yet. Thanks for trying but im not going to put php in mu theme layer.

Comment: @danielson317 We have a closing reason for questions asking to recommend or find a module; if you find any question about that, chances are the question will be closed, or it is closed already. Then, Drupal uses PHP in its theme layer, since preprocess functions are written in PHP.

Comment: @NoSssweat The same preprocess function could be implemented from a module, could not it be?

Comment: @kiamlaluno it can be. I still prefer not to use preprocess functions. Even if they are not in the theme they are using the theme layer. A view field formatter would be a better solution. A module or views extension snippet would be best.

Comment: `The same preprocess function could be implemented from a module` @kiamlaluno I believe that is true, if my memory is correct, I did that a long time ago and it worked. I just rather/like use template files instead of custom module.